How can I preserve these UV's when animating with bones?
I'm trying to make a face rig with a pixelated UV map. The mouth stretching (obviously) causes the UV to warp. I was wondering if there was any way to preserve the UV in the shader itself?
I have found the toggles for edit-mode to fix this issue, as seen in my edit-mode screenshot:
(This is what I want my bone to do, and not warp the UV)

Here is the same vertex parented to a bone. Can't figure out how to preserve the UV like this.

Thank you in advance!!!

Hello, if this is just a plane you could use the Generated output of the Texture Coordinate for example instead of the UV output?

After parenting to the rig, select the character (Main in my example), Shift D to duplicate it (renamed to "Projector), delete its Armature modifier, add to Main an UV project Modifier targeting at Projector, then make the projector invisible on rendering.


I'll give this a try, thank you!
